# How should I calculate sum of field grouped by another one using Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I've a collection Users which looks something like this-

```
{ "post": "teacher",
  "salary": 4500
},
{ "post": "teacher",
  "salary": 9000
},
{ "post": "principal",
  "salary": 7000
},
{ "post": "teacher",
  "salary": 4500
}
```

I want to calculate the total salary of all the teachers together and the same way for principals. So I want something which looks like

```
"teachers_salary": 18000
"principals_salary": 7000
```

I want to use aggregation but I'm not getting the desired output. It'd be really helpful if anyone of you can help me get a solution to this.

Comment: have you found an answer to your question yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of aggregating using spring-data-mongodb.

Assuming a results model object of PostTotalSalary.class:

```
public class PostTotalSalary {
    private String post; // "teacher" or "principal"
    private Integer totalSalary;
}
```

We will create a GroupOperation to gather all documents with the same value with a key of "post"

```
GroupOperation groupByPostAndSumSalary = group("post")
  .sum("salary")
  .as("totalSalary");
```

We can now use spring-data-mongodb to create an aggregation and then map the results to your results model object (assuming a collection name of "posts"):

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupByPostAndSumSalary);
AggregationResults<PostTotalSalary> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "posts", PostTotalSalary.class);
```

If you then want a list, AggregationResults has the getMappedResults method to do this:

```
List<PostTotalSalary> mappedResults = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

The end result will be

```
[
    {
        "post" : "teacher",
        "totalSalary" : "18000" // the total of all salaries for every "teacher" document
    },
    {
        "post" : "principal",
        "totalSalary" : "7000" // the total of all salaries for every "principal" document 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

On the mongoshell you can try this

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([ { 
    $group: { 
        _id: "$post", 
        totalsalary: { $sum: "$salary" }
    } 
} ] )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#mongodb-group-grp.-sum